# Different version of chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm wondering whether or not there is a symbol or value such as the chromatic number of a graph that asks

> What is the minimum coloring of the graph such that not only adjacent vertices have different colors, but vertices adjacent to a mutual vertices have different colors.

I'm just curious on whether this is a thing, or is it question that is easily related to the chromatic number and thus is not really thought much about.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this called the distance-2 coloring, where distance-k coloring asks for a vertex coloring where every two vertices of the same color are more than k steps apart. It's used in algorithms and computational results, but I'm not familiar with many of its properties.

Comment: Have there ever been distance-k colorings where distance-t vertices may be allowed to be the same colors?

Comment: When you search literature for distance-$k$ coloring, make sure you check out coloring of graph powers. A distance-$k$ coloring of graph $G$ is basically a coloring of the power graph $G^k$. In particular, for distance-2 coloring, also check coloring of square of graphs.

Comment: Also distance-2 coloring has a wide number of applications.